# Why can´t we assign a new string to a char array, but to a pointer?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

i was trying to reassign a string to a pre-initialized array a[], and all i could get was an error

```
main()
{
    char a[] = "Sunstroke";
    char *b = "Coldwave";

    a = "Coldwave";
    b = "Sunstroke";
    printf("\n %s %s",a,b);
}
```

[Error]: incompatible types when assigning to type 'char[10]' from type 'char *'.. i searched for this but was unable to find any reason.. i also tried to re-assign it by redeclaration like

```
char a[] = "Sunstroke";
```

but it didnt worked...

but in case of a pointer it was possible as in above program..

Comment: Why can we eat apples, but not love? Why can we swim in water, but not in molten boron? Because they're different things... Pointers are assignable, and arrays aren't.

Comment: Because array names cannot be modified. Again, arrays are not the same as pointers.

Comment: I'd like to flip it around and ask why you would want to do that -- what behavior are you hoping to evoke which is different from what you would get when `char *b = "Coldwave";`?

Comment: Use `std::string` and your problems go away.

Comment: Are you asking about C or C++? Arrays and pointers may have the same behaviour in both languages, but the idioms for manipulating strings are very different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hard-coded string literals such as "Coldwave" are actually `char[]` (char array) types -- but it is *undefined behavior* to modify them ([C99](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf):6.4.5.6).  Note that below, however, `b` is still a `char*` (char pointer):

```
char *b = "Coldwave";
```

To which a `char[]` has been assigned.  That's okay.  It is different than this though:

```
char a[] = "Coldwave";
```

Which is an *initialization* of a `char[]`.  You can only initialize a variable once, when it is declared, and initialization is the only circumstance in which you can populate an array or other compound type (such as a struct) via assignment like this.  You could not do this, however:

```
char c[] = a;
```

Because when used on the right hand side of an assignment, array variables function as pointers to the array they represent, which is why `char *b = a` works.

So the reason you can't do this with the variables from above:

```
a = b;
// or
a = "Sunstroke";
```

Is because that would be assigning a `char*` to a `char[]` -- no good; you can only do it the other way around.

Comment: i am just askig as to why the code `a = "coldwave";` creating an error.. and also if i redeclare it purposedly like `char a[] = "coldwave";` then it again creates an error saying redeclaration of variable..

Comment: Because the first one is an *assignment*, and **you can't assign anything to an array** -- you can only copy stuff into it.  The exception is when you declare the array, in which case it is *initialization*.  You can only initialize a variable once, when it is declared.  And **you can't redeclare identifiers** in C.  Once `a` exists within a given scope, you can't declare another `a`, even if it is of the same type.

Comment: "Hard-coded string literals such as "Coldwave" are treated as const char* types" Actually, it is of char array type.

Comment: To add to what @newacct said, it should be noted that arrays decay to `pointer of type` depending on the context, they are just not `lvalues`s in those cases. Just saying that arrays are different than pointer could be confusing considering that in many cases they will quite clearly act like a pointer i.e. passing as an argument to a function etc..

Answer (score 7):

To understand what's going on here, two language rules are important:

- Arrays are not assignable.
- An array can be converted to a pointer to its first element.

It's also important to understand what a *string literal* like `"Sunstroke"` is. It's a static array of constant characters, large enough to hold all the characters of a string with a terminator at the end. So in this case, it's a `const char[10]` array, containing the nine characters followed by the zero-valued terminator. Being *static*, the array is stored somewhere in memory for the lifetime of the program.

```
char a[] = "Sunstroke";
```

This creates a local array, and initialises it by copying the characters from the string literal.

```
char *b = "Coldwave";
```

This creates a pointer, and initialises it to point to the literal itself. Note that this is dangerous: the literal is `const`, but the pointer isn't, so you can write code that attempts to modify the literal, giving undefined behaviour. This conversion is deprecated (certainly in C++, I'm not sure about C), so the compiler should give you a warning. You have enabled all the compiler warnings you can, haven't you?

```
a = "Coldwave";
```

This attempts to reassign the array, but fails because arrays aren't assignable. There's no particularly good reason why they aren't; that's just the way the languages evolved.

```
b = "Sunstroke";
```

This reassigns the pointer to point to a different literal. That's fine (apart from the lack of `const` noted above).

If you need to manipulate strings, then:

- in C you'll need to carefully create arrays large enough for your needs, and use the library functions in `<string.h>` (or your own handcrafted code) to manipulate the characters in those arrays;
- in C++, use the `std::string` class to handle memory management, assignment, etc. for you.

Answer (score 3):

In the case of *C* if we look at [c99 draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) section `6.5.16` *Assignment operators* paragraph *2* says:

> An assignment operator shall have a modifiable lvalue as its left operand.

and section `6.3.2.1` *Lvalues, arrays, and function designators* paragraph *1* says:

> [...]A modifiable lvalue is an lvalue that does not have array type[...]

So since arrays are not modifiable lvalues you can not assign to them. As for initialization section `6.7.8` *Initialization* paragraph *14* says:

> An array of character type may be initialized by a character string literal[...]

In the [C++ draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) the relevant sections are `4.2` *Array-to-pointer conversion* paragraph *1* which says:

> An lvalue or rvalue of type “array of N T” or “array of unknown bound of T” can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to T”. The result is a pointer to the first element of the array.

a [prvalue](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category) is a pure rvalue and section `5.17` *Assignment and compound assignment operators* paragraph *1* which says:

> [...]All require a modifiable lvalue as their left operand[...]

Answer (score 1):

Let me simplify the program to:

```
char a[] = "Sunstroke";
char *b = a;
```

Assume that the address of `a` is 100, then in memory, it looks like this (illustrating only the size of pointer and endian-ness etc. may vary):

```
[S] [u] [n] [s] [t] [r] [o] [k] [e] [\0]         ...       [0] [0] [0] [100]
100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109                           200
 ^                                                                 ^
 |                                                                 |
 a                                                                 b
```

As long as the life cycle of the array, `a` will always be the same place, you can't modify it.

`b`, on the other hand, is a pointer that contains the address of the array, you **can** modify the value of `b` to point to other places.